# python and google cloud storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I can't find an example of how to use the google cloud storage WITHOUT running it on google appengine.

I want something like this (which works good for me): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-javascript/
but implemented in python instead.

So what I want to archive is that my frontend asks my python backend which then asks the cloud storage. I can't seam to find any examples that doesn't use appengine to authenticate, but it cant be impossible.

I've looked at both a couple of examples on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ but i can't find one without dependencies on appengine.

It also has to run on python3.

Comment: Have you find the solution to implement in python? Let us Know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) to access Google Cloud Storage from the command line. There is a [getting started tutorial here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started-gsutil).

There is a Python example using gsutil [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary):

> This tutorial shows you how to write a simple Python program that
>   performs basic Google Cloud Storage operations using the XML API.

Comment: Forgot to mention but it has to run on python3.4 and I can't install gsutil in python3.4.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for? blob has functions to download from file, upload to a file. You can do pretty much everything with GCS using these functions

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
blob = bucket.get_blob('path-to-file')
data = blob.download_as_string()
```

few more functions, they have some more

```
download_to_filename
upload_from_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) is the official Python client for interacting with GCS.

Python 3.x support was recently added, with the caveat:

> Python 3.3+ is also now supported! However, this library has not yet
>   been used as thoroughly with Python 3, so we'd recommend testing
>   before deploying with Python 3 in production.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question as there are a lot of python libraries floating around in addition to the gsutil cli.  This seems to be the latest supported python client by google

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

and the github is here

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/cloud-client